# Can't draw into JPanel during game loop

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to draw on a MapPanel which extends JPanel during the game loop, and it fails. However, If I do it at outside of a loop, it successfully draws. Here is my relevant code:

MenuPanel.java:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton pushedButton =(JButton) e.getSource();

    if(pushedButton == play)
        guiManager.setGamePanelVisible(true);
    else if(pushedButton == settings)
        guiManager.setSettingsPanelVisible();
    else if(pushedButton == credits)
        guiManager.setCreditsPanelVisible();
    else if(pushedButton == highScores)
        guiManager.setHighScoresPanelVisible();
    else if(pushedButton == help)
        guiManager.setHelpPanelVisible();

}
```

GUIManager.java:

```
...
    public void setGamePanelVisible(boolean gameStarted){
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(this);
        setContentPane(gp);
        gp.initiate();
    }
...
```

GamePanel.java

```
public void initiate(){
   this.gm = new GameManager(this);  // constructs the game manager and triggers the game loop 
}
```

GameManager.java

```
public GameManager(GamePanel gp) {
    this.gp = gp;
    this.run();
}

private void run(){
    while(running){
        draw();
        try{
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted at GameManager.java");
        }
    }
```

My prediction is, game loop starts while MenuPanel is still visible(at the setGamePanelVisible method), and since it never gets out that method, MenuPanel stays visible thus resulting in this situation. However, I may be wrong. Even if it is the problem, I couldnt think of any solution. Maybe I should move the button listener to another class? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where/what is the game loop?  How is it been called? It "sounds" like you are block the Event Dispatching Thread, but that's just a guess.Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Removed the irrelevant code and added some. I think that is what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Yep blocking the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: Your GameManager class ha to implement Runnable and start as a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is prevent the UI from been updated.  The EDT is responsible for, amongst other things, processing repaint requests.  Your game loop is running from within the context of the EDT...

`actionPerformed` is executed within the EDT, which calls `setGamePanelVisible`, which calls `GameManager` which calls `run`, which blocks...

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Swing is not thread safe, so you can't simply spin up a new `Thread` and hope that will fix everything, you need to ensure that all updates to the UI (including updates to information that the UI might need) and made from within the context of the EDT

One of the simpler solutions is to just use a Swing `Timer`, which will allow you to schedule regular, timed updates which are executed within the context of the EDT.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details